# In java 8, good practice to return stream of elements

Tags: java, java-8

Let say I have an object c of class C (from a library, so I cannot modify the class definition) which extend Iterable.

In my function, I want to provide a way for users to process a stream of objects of type R, where objects of type R are obtained by a transformation on objects of type T.

Currently I do the following:

```
Stream<R> f(...) {
  C c = ...;
  return StreamSupport.stream(c.spliterator(), false)
  .map(...);
}
```

It works because spliterator is implemented by default in class Iterable, but the javadoc says it is not advised to use default implementation for performance reasons.

I want to return a Stream to not create a List if the user just wants to process or apply stream operations on them.
I am not interested in parallelization properties of the stream, since objects in c can only be read in a sequential way.

So I wonder, whay is the recommened way, if any, to do this sort of thing. Is it better to simply return a List, or pass a consumer function as argument? I a a bit worried about the javadoc advising not to use default spliterator implem.
And with the method described above, can I be assured to preserve the order of elements appearance in the underlying Stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification doesn’t say that you shouldn’t use it. [It says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#spliterator--): “The default implementation should usually be overridden.” It’s clear that you can’t do anything about this regarding class `C` if you’re not the maintainer of the class `C`. But the important point is that the way you are using `C.spliterator()` does *not prevent* the maintainer of the class `C` to provide a customized implementation of `spliterator()` so there’s nothing wrong with that.

After all, the disadvantage of using the default `spliterator()` implementation like having no splitting capabilities applies to all other solutions as well. You can’t add such capabilities, only the maintainer of `C` can do that. The `Stream` you construct this way will not perform worse that using an ordinary `Iterator` as that’s exactly what the default implementation will use under the hood. But using a `Stream` allows to gain advantage of a future implementation of `C.spliterator()`.

If you know characteristics or the size of `C` you could [construct an optimized `Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliterator-java.util.Iterator-long-int-) but that would indeed interfere with a future evolution of class `C` and therefore used with care.